# What vim colorscheme is Red Hat EL7 setting by default and how can I port this to other systems?

Tags: vim, color-scheme, rhel7

I like the syntax highlighting that comes enabled with vim on Red Hat EL7.  I'd like to know what colorscheme it's using but when I type `:colorscheme` it says 'default'.

I'd like to replicate this colorscheme on MacOS and perhaps elsewhere but I'm not sure where to start.

[image]

Comment: I was hoping to migrate this to the vi/vim StackExchange site but apparently you can't migrate to a beta site.  Boo!  How is a beta supposed to get off the ground?

Answer (score 5):

All built-in colorschemes should be available in the `colors` directory of vim runtime. You can get to the directory using:

```
:e $VIMRUNTIME/colors
```

However, the default colorscheme uses this syntax file:

```
:e $VIMRUNTIME/syntax/syncolor.vim
```

You can use this vimcast as a reference for building your colorscheme: http://vimcasts.org/episodes/creating-colorschemes-for-vim/

P.S: I haven't used Red Hat EL7 before, could you please share a screenshot of how the `colorscheme` looks like?

Comment: Compared the syncolor.vim file on both systems and they are  identical.  They both report using the "default" colorscheme but look different!